# Custom tag handler

Tags: android, textview

I need to filter text before I set it to `Textview`. Im using couple filters and `Html.fromHtml` already but I encountered a problem. Tag `"{CROP(124,0,423,745)}"` (maybe followed with another instance for example : `{CROP(124,0,423,745)}` `{CROP(54,10,317,221)}`), which must be filtered this way:

1. Remove whole text starting with '{' until it reaches '}' and save this 4 integers
2. Create clickable span object (image with crop logo) and then set whole thing in `Textview`

What I found so far is: create `imagespan` and attach clickable span to it, but I'm not sure if this is the best way. But the problem is that `{CROP(124,0,423,745)}` instance may contain different number of characters in it like `{CROP(0,0,1,1)}` or `{CROP(1124,1130,2423,1745)}` and i don't know how to filters this data and then replace this string with a crop logo, and make it clickable.

Question: **What is the best way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great example of KRISHNA SHRESTHA helped me out;

http://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/tag/clickablespan/

Key is to use SpannableStringBuilder;

Thank you KRISHNA SHRESTHA